# CoreGraphics errors on rotation in iPad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext

While testing my universal app in the iPad simulator I get some weird Core Graphics errors when the app rotates. The app doesn't crash but the following is output to the console:

```
<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

In my app I have a `UITabBarController` as my root view controller which contains a navigation controller and two split view controllers in its tabs. I am forwarding rotation events etc to the split view controllers.

I think the problem lies somewhere in the split view controllers because one of the controllers has a detail view that contains an image view (also several labels and a text view) and one of the errors is `CGImageCreate`, but I could be way off. The detail view controller of the other split view controller is just a web view. Both the detail views were put together in IB.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code where you actually use any of the Core Graphics functions?  It's going to be impossible for us to help otherwise.

Comment: All the subsequent errors are likely a result of the first one. Set a symbolic breakpoint on `CGPostError` to have the debugger stop when displaying one of these errors.